# c++ parsing data from file I/O

Tags: c++

I am writing code to 1. read in from a file via command line argument, 2. parse through each line of data (string) and 3. split the data into 4 substrings.

say I have game.txt

```
3
overwatch|hanzo|junkrat|reinhart
league of legends|vayne|ezreal|master yi
starcraft|marine|zergling|zealot
```

the output that I want is each to have each line of data be splited into 4 substrings and I want to save each respective column to some sort of container. Possibly linkedlist of Strings, or array of strings.
So,

```
overwatch
hanzo
junkrat
reinhart
league of legend
vayne
ezreal
...


String nameOfGame = overwatch;
String leastFav = hanzo;
String fav = junkrat;
String bestCharacter = reinhart;
```

I've tried several ways to go about this problem, but I cannot see the logic to have string read in and parsed at the same time. The concept is still new to me, and I need some advice on where to start and how to approach the problem.

What could I do here?

Comment: Please show your attempt. This will help get you better answers.

Comment: If each row always has the same contents, consider defining a class and using a std::vector of that class.

Comment: You can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the lines from the file.  Countless examples on Stack Overflow.  You can use the same function to read `|`-delimited strings from a `std::istringstream`.  There are also helper `getline` member functions on all the stream classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) to read first number and [lines](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) from file.
For getting data from the any line, you can use [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/?kw=istringstream). You can create the istringstream object with the line string. 
After that you can read components from the line by using method [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) with delim = '|'.

After that you can print lines as you want

```
using String = std::string;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    std::ifstream inputFileStream("Input.txt");
    int count;
    inputFileStream>>count;
    inputFileStream.ignore(1, '\n');

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        String line;
        std::getline(inputFileStream, line);

        std::istringstream lineStream(line);

        String nameOfGame;
        String leastFav;
        String fav;
        String bestCharacter;

        std::getline(lineStream, leastFav, '|');
        std::getline(lineStream, nameOfGame, '|');
        std::getline(lineStream, fav, '|');
        std::getline(lineStream, bestCharacter, '|');

        std::cout<< leastFav <<"\n"<<nameOfGame<<"\n"<<fav<<"\n"<<bestCharacter<<"\n\n";
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. I did read a few examples about istringstream and I did not fully understand how it is used. I will try this again and post follow up status.